# Adding Virgin Islands and Puerto Rico to CartoDB?

Tags: carto, natural-earth

I am new to Cartodb.

I have started with the ne_50m_admin_1_states data.

How can I add Virgin Islands and Puerto Rico?

Is there geometry I can get?

Is there an easy way to add them?

Answer (score 2):

You can add two rows to your current dataset and write "Virgin Islands" and "Puerto Rico" in the column that stores the name of the locations.

Then, you can georeference your table by using "By administrative regions" and selecting the column for the name in the first selector, leaving the second one empty.

That should geocode Virgin Islands and Puerto Rico as polygons.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what a cool feature!

Answer (score 1):

Worldwide, public domain data at multiple scales is available here, http://www.naturalearthdata.com/.

You will have to clip out the area that you want with GIS software or conversely, get rid of the data you have now and use this data as it has been built to work together well. Actually it looks like the data you are using is part of Natural Earth Data, so I would definitely scrap it and download the new data.